# css block links and images

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Given this html:

```
<div class="nation">
    <a href="library.php?type=nation&amp;id=America">
        <div class="nation-image">
            <img src="nations/America.png" alt="snip" />
        </div>
        <h3>America</h3>
    </a>
</div>
```

the following CSS results in the entire `<div class="nation">` becoming a clickable block link:

```
.nation {float: left; text-align: center; width: 189px;}

.nation img {width: 160px; margin: 10px 0 0 0; border: 1px solid #16160C;}
```

but if I make the following single addition:

```
.nation {float: left; text-align: center; width: 189px;}

    .nation-image {height: 138px;}

.nation img {width: 160px; margin: 10px 0 0 0; border: 1px solid #16160C;}
```

to specify the height of `<div class="nation-image">` then the image (and only the image) is no longer a link, but the rest of the div (margin around it, `h3` etc) remain a block link.

I am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/uyupu/2

your HTML struct must be someting like this:

```
<div class="nation">
<a href="#">
    <img src="your.jpg" alt="Daim Graffiti" id="usa" />
    <span class="nation-flag">America</span>
</a>
</div>
```

then your CSS:

```
    .nation {
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      float: left;
      position: relative;
    }
    .nation a {
      text-decoration: none;
      float: left;
    }
    .nation a:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .nation a img {
      float: left;
      margin: 0;
      border: none;
      padding: 10px;
      background: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;

/* note that you don't really need to set the Height 
but the width so the image auto scaling fine!*/

      width:200px
    }

    .nation a .nation-flag {
      position: absolute;
      right: 20px;
      bottom: 20px;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      color: #fff;
      background: #000;
      padding: 5px 10px;
      filter:alpha(opacity=65);
      opacity:.65;
      -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=65)"; 
    /*--IE 8 Transparency--*/
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't wrap block elements with inline elements like anchor tags. Put a call to a location-changing function right into clickable image, or even do it inline, as in the following rudimentary example:

```
<img src="nations/America.png" alt="snip" 
   onclick="javascript:location.href='library.php?type=nation&amp;id=America'" />
```

Then just float your image however you like.

Comment: I would go as far as moving the onclick to the first div, since the OP wants the entire thing clickable. Showing an unobtrusive option would be nice too!

Answer (score 0):

This is invalid html try:

```
<div class="nation">
     <h3><a href="library.php?type=nation&amp;id=America" class="nation-flag" id="usa">
       America
    </a></h3>
</div>
```

You can then have a generic class for all flags. And then be specific for #usa and apply the flag as a background image. Using CSS you can display the href as a block and make it as big as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use your div.nation as a.nation instead. Add "display: block" to it to make it affect the entire parent div.